# How can I write this function?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to write this in the `\addplot` to graph a function, but it always gives me error, it is possible?

```
$f(x)=\frac{x^{2}+5}{x-1}$
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,fit,calc}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat = newest} % specify to the compiler that we are working with the 
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[]
             \addplot[red, thick]{\frac{x^{2}+5}{x-1}};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use LaTeX syntax in your plot command, but that won't work; try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,fit,calc}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat = newest} % specify to the compiler that we are working with the 
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[]
             \addplot[smooth, samples=250, domain=-5:0.5, red, thick]{(x^2+5)/(x-1)};
             \addplot[smooth, samples=250, domain=1.5:5, red, thick]{(x^2+5)/(x-1)};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

(I've split the plot into two parts here since your function has a pole at 1.)

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing. You may want to use `domain=-6:0.9` and `domain=1.1:6` if you want to see more of your curve. But it's mandatory to avoid the pole by splitting the plot into two separated parts.